# SQLite database hosted on Heroku getting automatically reset

Tags: php, heroku

I've a very simple Facebook application hosted on Heroku which uses PHP for back-end and SQLite for storage. For some weird reason, the SQLite database gets randomly reset to the last version I pushed. Can someone help me understand the reason behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku has an [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) that loses any changes each time the dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting). You should store SQL lite files on amazon or use an Heroku database.