# Deploy flask web app with sqlite database via heroku

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I've tried to make a website using flask using a sqlite database and deploy it via heroku, but apparently heroku doesn't support sqlite, it able to deploy but the database is deleted after a while.  If I want to deploy using another service or buy my own domain, will the database be fine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Added database records are deleted after restarting app (heroku/SQLAlchemy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454885/added-database-records-are-deleted-after-restarting-app-heroku-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 1):

Heroku does support sqlite database.

But since Heroku has an ephemeral file system so the files created during program run are deleted on dyno restart.

Using another service may solve it, it depends on the service you are using.

A good solution would be to use a remote database. Heroku itself has an add on to add a postgresql.

**Edit:** Here is an article from devcenter.heroku which explains why sqlite doesn't work and shouldn't be used also explaining how to create an external database as addon.
[Here is the article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).