# Heroku db delete

Tags: python, heroku

The database in my heroku test application is deleted automatically after a while. Only data that was present when I deployed is protected. the others are deleted after 3 or 5 hours or so. Why am I experiencing this? What should I do?

Comment: what database are you using? Heroku is using an ephemeral filesystem which is wiped every time the dyno is restarted. 

So any local data is temporary, you have to use [one of the data store addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#data-stores) to store your data.

Comment: sqlalchemy database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because `Heroku` has a temporary filesystem `(Ephemeral Filesystem)`. So when a `dyno` is restarted, all changes made to the application up to that time are undone and restored to the state you deployed.

Similar solutions are already available for this:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting

[Added database records are deleted after restarting app (heroku/SQLAlchemy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454885/added-database-records-are-deleted-after-restarting-app-heroku-sqlalchemy)

[SQLite database hosted on Heroku getting automatically reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552742/sqlite-database-hosted-on-heroku-getting-automatically-reset/13552761#13552761)